# MS WORD VBA Find Replace text using a variable

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have a variable (strLastname) that I use to send a string to a bookmark. That works well.
I also wish to use that variable to replace temporary text "Name>" in a long document.

This is what I have now.

```
  Sub cmdOK_Click()
    Dim strLastname As String   ' from dialogue box "BoxLastname" field
    strLastname = BoxLastname.Value
....
  End sub
```

The macro that does not work:

```
Sub ClientName()

Selection.Find.ClearFormatting
Selection.Find.Replacement.ClearFormatting
With Selection.Find
    .Text = "Name>"
    .Replacement.Text = strLastname??????

             'Selection.TypeText (strLastname) ????
              'How to use the variable from the Dialogue Box - strLastname????

     End With
  Selection.Find.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
End Sub
```

I tried 
.`Replacement.Text = strLastname  and   .Replacement.Text = BoxLastname.Value`   but no one work.

Answer (score 3):

A quick search from google finds this link
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa211953(v=office.11).aspx

I tried this on a simple document to find and replace text

```
With ActiveDocument.Content.Find
    .Forward = True
    .Wrap = wdFindStop
    .Execute FindText:="Text", ReplaceWith:="Tax", Replace:=wdReplaceAll
```

That replaces all occurence of Text with Tax .... is this what you're after ??

Works with variables too

```
OldWord = "VAT"
NewWord = "Text"

With ActiveDocument.Content.Find
    .Forward = True
    .Wrap = wdFindStop
    .Execute FindText:=OldWord, ReplaceWith:=NewWord, Replace:=wdReplaceAll, Matchcase:=True
End With
```

Add , Matchcase:=True at end to fix case problem (modified now above)

3rd Modification results in this

```
Dim strLastname As String   ' from dialogue box "BoxLastname" field
strLastname = BoxLastname.Value

OldWord = "Name"
NewWord = strLastName

With ActiveDocument.Content.Find
    .Forward = True
    .Wrap = wdFindStop
    .Execute FindText:=OldWord, ReplaceWith:=NewWord, Replace:=wdReplaceAll, Matchcase:=True
End With
```

Comment: Thanks. My goal is to replace several occurence of a temporary word by a variable taken fron a dialogue box where the Clien's name typed in. This avriable is use to send the string to a bookmark ans thats works well. But how to use this variable (strLastname) to replace the temporary text "Name>" in my very long document?

Comment: modified answer for variables ... they went to uppercase for me ... checking that now

Comment: I think thats the answer but if you've more clarifications needed just ask, if not and we're sorted please tick the answer

Comment: OldWord = strLastname
NewWord = "Name"   in sample code above

Comment: Thanks guys, you are very nice. This is the code I have now and still does not work.Sub ClientName() OldWord = "Name>" NewWord = strLastname With ActiveDocument.Content.Find .Forward = True .Wrap = wdFindStop .Execute FindText:=OldWord, ReplaceWith:=NewWord, Replace:=wdReplaceAll End With End Sub   >>>>I still cannot understand why the variable StrLastname can not be "re-use" to do a Find/Replace. The variable is properley declared: Sub cmdOK_Click()
    Dim strLastname As String   ' from dialogue box "BoxLastname" field
    strLastname = BoxLastname.Value
....
  End sub

Comment: You need to take my code and place it into a Sub you already have where the strLastName variable already exists.   What you have done will not work because the new Sub you have created has no idea what is in strLastName.  Combine the code above with your own code

Comment: My final edit just done. Modified the Answer. Hope you can finish off from here.  The objective here is to help you see the way forward, not to do all the work for you though.

Comment: Thanks a lot. All that info will help to find a solution. Have a nice day.